# Let $g:A\rightarrow R$ and assume f is a bounded function on$A\subseteq R$. Show that if$\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x \to c }g(x)f(x) =0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof

let $\epsilon > 0$,$\delta >0$

since f(x) is bounded function then we have

$$0<x<\delta \leftrightarrow  |f(x)-L|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$$

and g has limit equal 0

$$0<x<\delta \leftrightarrow  |g(x|<\sqrt{\epsilon }$$

for $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}g(x)f(x)=0

$$0< x< \delta \leftrightarrow |f(x)-L||g(x|)< \sqrt{\epsilon }\sqrt{\epsilon }=\epsilon $$

Choose $\delta =\epsilon $

then $|f(x)-L||g(x|<\epsilon $ or limit equal 0

Comment: Your proof is not well organized. You don't need to assume $\delta$. Next, your definition of a bounded function is not correct. And lot more...

Comment: I forgot f(x) is bounded function -*-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded on $A$, there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in A$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Using the assumption that $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=0$ (applied on $\frac{\epsilon}{M}$), we can find a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $x\in A$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$, we have
$$|g(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{M}.$$ Hence, if $x\in A$ and $0<|x-c|<\delta$ then
$$|f(x)g(x)-0|=|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)|\cdot|g(x)|\leq M|g(x)|<M\frac{\epsilon}{M}=\epsilon.$$ This proves that $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)g(x)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Solve like this
Since ff is bounded on AA, there exists M>0M>0 such that |f(x)|≤M|f(x)|≤M for all x∈Ax∈A. Let ϵ>0ϵ>0. Using the assumption that limx→cg(x)=0limx→cg(x)=0 (applied on ϵMϵM), we can find a δ>0δ>0 such that whenever 0<|x−c|<δ0<|x−c|<δ, we have
|g(x)|<ϵM.
|g(x)|<ϵM.
Hence, if 0<|x−c|<δ0<|x−c|<δ then
|f(x)g(x)−0|=|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)|⋅|g(x)|≤M|g(x)|